# SQL Why the below query is very slow when add more where conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-optimization

I have met a strange problem for my SQL query is very slow when I add some more conditions.

My tables:

```
CREATE TABLE[dbo].[ASSETS_INFO]
(
[ASSET_ID][int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[OBJECT_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
[EQUIPMENT_ID] [nvarchar] (20) NOT NULL,
[EQUIPMENT_NAME] [nvarchar] (100) NULL,
[USER_NO] [nvarchar] (20) NULL,
[PRODUCTER] [int] NULL,
[ASSET_TYPE] [nvarchar] (20) NULL,

CONSTRAINT[PK_ASSETS_INFO] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
(
[ASSET_ID] ASC
)WITH(PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON[PRIMARY]
) ON[PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON[PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[BM_METERINFO](
[METER_ID] [varchar](40) NOT NULL,
[CUSTOMER_ID] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
[CUSTOMER_NAME] [varchar](200) NULL,

CONSTRAINT [PK_BM_METERINFO] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
  [METER_ID] ASC,
  [CUSTOMER_ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[WSMP_OBJECT](
    [OBJECT_ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [OBJECT_NAME] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [OBJECT_STATE] [int] NOT NULL,
    [OBJECT_INDEX] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_WSMP_OBJECT] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
   [OBJECT_ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

My SQL query 1:

```
declare @table_count_f1 table
(
OBJECT_ID INT
);
insert into @table_count_f1
select OBJECT_ID from[FNNC_WAPCONFIG_AUTHOR_AREA_WSMPOBJECTIDS] ('2', 'lams_v2_dev', 0, '')  order by OBJECT_ID   -- get all object_ids which is very quick (more than 60,000 rows)

declare @table_count_f2 table
(
OBJECT_ID INT
);
insert into @table_count_f2
SELECT DISTINCT obj.OBJECT_ID FROM[ASSETS_INFO] A
INNER JOIN[WSMP_OBJECT] OBJ ON OBJ.OBJECT_ID = A.OBJECT_ID
LEFT JOIN dbo.BM_METERINFO bm ON A.USER_NO = BM.CUSTOMER_ID and a.EQUIPMENT_ID = bm.METER_ID
WHERE OBJ.OBJECT_STATE in (0, 1, -2) AND(A.SYS_DATA_STATE <> -1 OR A.SYS_DATA_STATE IS NULL)
    AND A.ASSET_TYPE in('22')
    And case  WHEN bm.METER_ID IS  null THEN 1 WHEN bm.METER_ID = '' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END = 1
    --here is the problem: it got the result when I use either of 'AND',but it runs very slowly when I use both of them.I have added index already
order by OBJECT_ID

select count(*) from @table_count_f1 t1,@table_count_f2 t2
where t1.OBJECT_ID = t2.OBJECT_ID
```

Execution plan

[image]

[image]

My SQL query 2:

```
declare @table_count_f0 table
(
OBJECT_ID INT
);
insert into @table_count_f0
select OBJECT_ID from[FNNC_WAPCONFIG_AUTHOR_AREA_WSMPOBJECTIDS]('2', 'lams_v2_dev', 0, '') order by OBJECT_ID

SELECT A.*, OBJ.OBJECT_INDEX, OBJ.OBJECT_STATE,
case  WHEN bm.METER_ID IS  null THEN 1 WHEN bm.METER_ID = '' THEN 1 ELSE 2 end setState FROM[ASSETS_INFO] A
INNER JOIN[WSMP_OBJECT] OBJ ON OBJ.OBJECT_ID = A.OBJECT_ID
LEFT JOIN dbo.BM_METERINFO bm ON a.EQUIPMENT_ID = bm.METER_ID AND A.USER_NO = BM.CUSTOMER_ID
WHERE OBJ.OBJECT_STATE IN(0,1,-2) AND(A.SYS_DATA_STATE <> -1 OR A.SYS_DATA_STATE IS NULL)

and OBJ.OBJECT_ID in (select OBJECT_ID from @table_count_f0 )
        and case  WHEN bm.METER_ID IS  null THEN 1 WHEN bm.METER_ID = '' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END = 2
ORDER BY A.EQUIPMENT_NAME asc
        OFFSET 20 ROWS
        FETCH NEXT 20 ROWS ONLY
```

The problem is in `ORDER BY`, when I use `ORDER BY EQUIPMENT_ID` it is very quick, but when I use `ORDER BY EQUIPMENT_NAME`  it is slow, I added an index for `ASSETS_INFO` in SSMS but it has no effect.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: We need an execution plan to provide performance advice. Please google Paste The Plan. And you might find better support on https://dba.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: I suggest adding paste the plan as well as the image.

Comment: 1) convert your table variable to a temp table.

Comment: If this query is used by an application, you really should just remove the sorting altogether and stick it in the application. Other programming languages are much better suited to performing sort operations

Comment: @Oakley I don't agree with that, with the correct indexes SQL Server can sort as fast as it can retrieve the data.

Comment: @DaleK I definitely agree it can do it, what I was meaning is that sorting is resource heavy no matter how you do it. Whenever I have a query that needs optimization, the first thing I do is limit the amount of sorting done on the db server as much as possible which often leads to sorting in the application where the impact is only felt by the one user instead of everyone connected to the database.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you already have a covering index on WSMP_OBJECT (OBJECT_ID), as well as the new index on EQUIPMENT_NAME having includes to cover the query.

Your main issue here is the sort by the looks of things. A combination of the fact you are distincting over the whole resultset combined with SQL Server not understanding what you are trying to do with the left join means it sorts again even it could get the data sorted already.

Essentially what you want is a semi-join against WSMP_OBJECT and an anti-join against BM_METERINFO.

```sql
SELECT
    obj.OBJECT_ID
FROM [ASSETS_INFO] A
INNER JOIN [WSMP_OBJECT] OBJ ON OBJ.OBJECT_ID = A.OBJECT_ID
WHERE OBJ.OBJECT_STATE in (0, 1, -2)
    AND (A.SYS_DATA_STATE <> -1 OR A.SYS_DATA_STATE IS NULL)
    AND A.ASSET_TYPE in('22')
    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
        FROM dbo.BM_METERINFO bm
        WHERE A.USER_NO = BM.CUSTOMER_ID and a.EQUIPMENT_ID = bm.METER_ID
        AND bm.METER_ID <> '')
order by OBJECT_ID
```

Similarly (here I believe setState will always be 2):

```sql
SELECT
    A.*,
    OBJ.OBJECT_INDEX,
    OBJ.OBJECT_STATE,
    2 setState
FROM [ASSETS_INFO] A
INNER JOIN [WSMP_OBJECT] OBJ ON OBJ.OBJECT_ID = A.OBJECT_ID
WHERE OBJ.OBJECT_STATE IN(0,1,-2) AND(A.SYS_DATA_STATE <> -1 OR A.SYS_DATA_STATE IS NULL)
and OBJ.OBJECT_ID in (select OBJECT_ID from @table_count_f0 )
    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
        FROM dbo.BM_METERINFO bm
        WHERE A.USER_NO = BM.CUSTOMER_ID and a.EQUIPMENT_ID = bm.METER_ID
        AND bm.METER_ID <> '')
ORDER BY A.EQUIPMENT_NAME asc
        OFFSET 20 ROWS
        FETCH NEXT 20 ROWS ONLY
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not know why below code is faster, it still seems to be related to index.

Modified SQL QUERY 1:

```
declare @table_count_f1 table
(
OBJECT_ID INT
);
insert into @table_count_f1
select OBJECT_ID from [FNNC_WAPCONFIG_AUTHOR_AREA_WSMPOBJECTIDS] ('2', 'lams_v2_dev', 0, '')  order by OBJECT_ID

declare @table_count_f2 table
(
OBJECT_ID INT,
PRODUCTER INT,
ASSET_TYPE INT
);
insert into @table_count_f2
SELECT DISTINCT obj.OBJECT_ID,A.PRODUCTER,A.ASSET_TYPE FROM [ASSETS_INFO] A 
INNER JOIN[WSMP_OBJECT] OBJ ON OBJ.OBJECT_ID = A.OBJECT_ID
LEFT JOIN dbo.BM_METERINFO bm ON  A.USER_NO = BM.CUSTOMER_ID and a.EQUIPMENT_ID = bm.METER_ID 
WHERE OBJ.OBJECT_STATE in (0,1,-2) AND(A.SYS_DATA_STATE <> -1 OR A.SYS_DATA_STATE IS NULL) 
--AND A.ASSET_TYPE in('22') 
-- AND A.PRODUCTER in ('1')
and case  WHEN bm.METER_ID IS  null THEN 1 WHEN bm.METER_ID='' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END=1 
 AND OBJ.OBJECT_STATE in(1) 
order by OBJECT_ID


select count(*) from @table_count_f1 t1,@table_count_f2 t2
where t1.OBJECT_ID=t2.OBJECT_ID 
AND t2.PRODUCTER in ('1')
AND t2.ASSET_TYPE in ('22')
```